# How to fill ComboBox in C# WinForms "Data Change Form" with EF6

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, combobox

I have a Problem with Windows Forms and Entity Framework.

In the database there are 3 related entities:

**Person** *  ------  0/1 **PostalCodeCity** *------ 1 **Country**

```
TABLE: Person
----------
Name
PostalCode

TABLE: PostalCodeCity
----------
PostalCode
CityName
CountryCode

TABLE: Country
----------
CountryCode
CountryName
ISOCurrency
Tax
```

What i want to achieve is a form, where i can edit persons. So far so good, I drag and drop the entities from my DataSource Window in Visual Studio and everything fine so far **BUT** :

PostalCode, and CountryName should be show as DropDown-Element. By now they are displayed as DropDown but i can't choose other values!

So what i need to achieve is that by default the selected items in these two ComboBoxes are the current values and per drop-down i want to be able to change them.
The next difficulty for me is: only the postal code from the selected country should be available.

I'm very thankful for every kind of help :)

Comment: Person! i want to be able to change the Country and PostalCode of a Person